# React-native-fetch-blob downloading file

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I just want my app download a file from the server by using react-native-fetch-blob. The problem is, where do the file stored? I just console.log the callback from react-native-fetch-blob and got this object

[React-native-fetch-blob object callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNzpn.png)

this is my code

```
alert("downloading");
RNFetchBlob
    .config({
        useDownloadManager : true, 
        fileCache : true
    })    
    .fetch('GET', 'http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip', {})
    .then((res) => {

        console.log(res);
        alert("Download");
        alert('The file saved to ', res.path());
    })
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 5):

To download a file directly with rn-fetch-blob, you need to set fileCache as true.

btw, [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) is not maintained anymore, use [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) instead

[document of download file directly](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#download-to-storage-directly)

```
RNFetchBlob
  .config({
    // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
    // this is much more performant.
    fileCache : true,
  })
  .fetch('GET', 'http://www.example.com/file/example.zip', {
    //some headers ..
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // the temp file path
    console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function downloadFile(url,fileName) {
  const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob;
  const downloads = fs.dirs.DownloadDir;
  return config({
    // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
    // this is much more performant.
    fileCache : true,
    addAndroidDownloads : {
      useDownloadManager : true,
      notification : false,
      path:  downloads + '/' + fileName + '.pdf',
    }
  })
  .fetch('GET', url);
}
```

use this answer it will work for sure

Comment: I don't understand how you did it but you crashed the app

Answer (score 0):

I am using it and it works perfectly.
You just need to get the path like this.

```
var filePath = res.path();
```

this is where your file is stored.

Comment: I have doing it before but it return empty string